# Web Services no conecta con versiones superiores a Android 8 (Android Studio)

Tags: android-studio, api, webservice, aplicación-web, programación-móvil

Hola tengo un problema inmenso, resulta que he ejecutado mi apk con versiones de Android 6/7 y funciona la APK correctamente, hasta conecta con webservices sin problemas....pero al instalar el aplicativo en otros dispositivos de version superior no se conecta con el webservice.
La conexion es por medio de Volley en Android Studio y los permisos en el Manifest los tengo así:

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /
```

esto es lo que aparece en LOGCAT al ejecutar la apk:

```
2020-08-02 12:41:48.056 6970-7035/com.example.appeunice W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2020-08-02 12:41:48.370 6970-7035/com.example.appeunice D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
2020-08-02 12:41:48.371 6970-7035/com.example.appeunice E/eglCodecCommon: GoldfishAddressSpaceHostMemoryAllocator: ioctl_ping failed for device_type=5, ret=-1
2020-08-02 12:41:48.479 6970-7035/com.example.appeunice D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe1d85240: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe1d83670)
2020-08-02 12:41:49.278 6970-7035/com.example.appeunice I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=1397ms; Flags=0, IntendedVsync=334983747562, Vsync=335233747552, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=335239103600, AnimationStart=335239192900, PerformTraversalsStart=335239801100, DrawStart=335544052000, SyncQueued=335584808100, SyncStart=335646103300, IssueDrawCommandsStart=335653933500, SwapBuffers=336362562000, FrameCompleted=336442960200, DequeueBufferDuration=542000, QueueBufferDuration=2732000, 
2020-08-02 12:41:49.318 6970-6970/com.example.appeunice I/Choreographer: Skipped 73 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2020-08-02 12:41:49.386 6970-7035/com.example.appeunice I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=1295ms; Flags=0, IntendedVsync=335251174455, Vsync=336467841073, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=336482715200, AnimationStart=336482909300, PerformTraversalsStart=336483590000, DrawStart=336487160100, SyncQueued=336493261200, SyncStart=336496746100, IssueDrawCommandsStart=336513832500, SwapBuffers=336537229900, FrameCompleted=336550439200, DequeueBufferDuration=777000, QueueBufferDuration=6401000,
```

y esto me aparece en el LOGCAT al ejecutar el boton:

```
2020-08-02 12:00:14.867 6930-6930/com.example.appeunice W/ample.appeunic: Verification of org.apache.http.HttpResponse com.android.volley.toolbox.BaseHttpStack.performRequest(com.android.volley.Request, java.util.Map) took 278.836ms
2020-08-02 12:00:14.899 6930-7275/com.example.appeunice D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
```

Obtengo los datos por medio de 000WebHost con de metodos de conexion en PHP y MySql para enviarlos en formato JSON.

FUNCIONA BIEN EN VERSIONES DE ANDROID 6/7, PERO NO FUNCIONA EN VERSIONES SUPERIORES
Quién me pueda ayudar estaría muy agradecido ya que llevo muchísimo tiempo con este problema que no he podido solucionar.

Comment: Revisa el Logcat de Android Studio, copia la traza completa del error y agregala a la pregunta.

Comment: ¿Por qué quitaste el otro Logcat? Ahí aparecía un error, aquí son solo advertencias, no errores.

Comment: Es importante agregar la imnformacion que comenta A. Cedano, revisa en el LogCat donde diga "Caused by" y agregala a tu pregunta. Cual es el sistema operativo del dispositivo donde falla?

Comment: Perdón, es que soy muy nuevo en esto.

esto es lo que aparece en LOGCAT al ejecutar la apk

Comment: Dices que funciona en versiones 6 y 7 pero no en nuevas, por eso es importante agregar en que OS esta fallando, ClearText se deshabilita para partir de Android 9 (API nivel 28).

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontré la solución:

el problema era que no tenía agregada esta linea en el manifest:

```
android:usescleartexttraffic="true"
```

Al parecer esta linea no es necesaria si vas a usar el aplicativo en **versiones iguales o inferiores de android 7**

Comment: Lo que comentas **es a partir del nivel de API 28 ya que la compatibilidad de Cleartext está inhabilitada de forma predeterminada** y no para versiones superiores a Android 7 como comentas, revisa la documentacion oficial:  https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config?hl=es-419